# Add ExtJS components at run time - "refresh view"?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am adding components to a panel at runtime:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.SomePanel",{
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    ...
    setGridList:function(gridIds) {
        myItems=[];
        Ext.each(gridIds,function(gridId){ myItems.push(Ext.getCmp(gridId) || Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel",{id:gridId}))});
        Ext.applyIf(me,{items:myItems});
    }
});
```

It works well when called for the first time, from the initComponent. But it does not work when called from a store load handler. My best guess is that I have to refresh the view, rebuild the layout or sth. like that!? But I don't find such a thing in the docs.

Anyone here knows the trick?

Comment: Does you `SomePanel` extend another Component? If yes, which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class `MyApp.view.SomePanel` is an Ext component, than you could use the [Container.add()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-add) or [Container.remove()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-remove).

If the child is not automatically added, call the [Container.doLayout() method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-doLayout).

PS: the layout of your class should support multiple children.